# Arabic-English Transliteration using unsupported font

Tags: utf-8, fonts, character-encoding, nlp, arabic

I am working on language transliteration for Ar and En text.

Here is the link which displays character by character replacement : https://github.com/Shnoulle/Ar-PHP/blob/master/Arabic/data/Transliteration.xml

Now issue is:

I am dealing with font style `robert_bold.ttf` and `robert_regular_0.ttf` which has some typical characters with `underline` and `overline` as in this snap

[image]

I have .ttf file so I can see this fonts on my system. But in my application or in above `Transliteration.xml` characters are considered as junk like `[, } [` etc.

How can I add support of this unsupported characters in `Transliteration.xml` file?

```
<pair>
  <search>ي</search>
  <replace>y</replace>
</pair>
<pair>
  <search>ى</search>
  <replace>a</replace>
</pair>
<pair>
  <search>أ</search>
  <replace>^</replace> // Here is one of the character s_ (s with underscore not supported)
</pair>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the font is not Unicode encoded but contains the underlined letters at some arbitrarily assigned codes. While this works up to a point, it does not work across applications, of course. It works only when that specific font is used.

The proper way is to use correct Unicode *characters* such as U+1E0F LATIN SMALL LETTER D WITH LINE BELOW “ḏ” and, for rendering, try to find [fonts containing it](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1e0f/fontsupport.htm).

An alternative is to use just basic Latin letters with some markup, say `<u>d</u>`. This means that the text must not be treated as plain text in later processing, and in rendering, the markup should be interpreted as requesting for a line under the letter(s).

Comment: thanks dear. But system for which I am working has given me Fonts. And it is not in the list of the link you gave. The text I would be processing would be in that 'Fonts' only. I can send your even that font. I am still wondering how to get read of this

Comment: If you can and must work with one special font using a special encoding, you need to identify that encoding, e.g. testing different character repertoires in it or using a font inspector. But it sounds that not all software in your production chain can handle the font. You wrote: “in my application [...] characters are considered as junk like [, } [”. Why would they be junk? It seems that they are what you have got *at the character level*; your font is supposed to render them as something quite different. So in which sense are they “junk”?

Comment: They are not available in my application so they appear as junk characters.

Comment: @cyclic, “junk” is not a description. A screenshot might help. But most importantly, you need to describe the problem in a reproduceable way. How have you programmed your application to render the XML file? Does it use the special font you have mentioned?

Comment: Yes, it uses special font i mentioned. For now, it works for me using `special charcter like {`. it consider it as respective character in English while performing transliteration